# Algolia Android initial search is really slow

Tags: android, search, algolia

I recently implemented Algolia on my app successfully just like [the examples](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android).

But the initial search takes about 5 to 7 seconds and I couldn't find a way to make it faster after checking the whole library code and documentation. After the initial search, search becomes very fast.

There is nothing unusual in my implementation but maybe you can see something that I don't. The following code is from the activity where I initialize Algolia:

```
    Searcher searcher = new Searcher(ALGOLIA_APP_ID, ALGOLIA_SEARCH_API_KEY, ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);
    searcher.setQuery(new Query("word").setExactOnSingleWordQuery(Query.ExactOnSingleWordQuery.ATTRIBUTE));
    searcher.addNumericRefinement(new NumericRefinement("CountryId", NumericRefinement.OPERATOR_EQ, 1));
    InstantSearch helper = new InstantSearch(this, searcher);
    helper.setSearchOnEmptyString(false);
    helper.search();
```

And this is the related xml layout:

```
<FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:paddingBottom="6dp"
   android:paddingRight="10dp"
   android:paddingLeft="1dp"
   android:paddingTop="6dp">

   <com.algolia.instantsearch.ui.views.SearchBox
   android:id="@+id/searchBox"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:queryHint="@string/search_text_hint"
   algolia:searchIcon="@drawable/icn_search_big"
   algolia:closeIcon="@drawable/icn_clear_filled_big"
   android:queryBackground="@drawable/sarch_query_shape"
   android:background="@drawable/search_shape"
   algolia:autofocus="true"
   algolia:submitButtonEnabled="false" />
 </FrameLayout>`
 <com.algolia.instantsearch.ui.views.Hits
    android:id="@+id/hits"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    algolia:autoHideKeyboard="true"
    algolia:hitsPerPage="6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchBarParentLayout"
    algolia:infiniteScroll="false"
    algolia:itemLayout="@layout/search_item_algolia_row"/>
```

Do you have any idea what can be the issue here?

Comment: Interesting.. if you remove `helper.setSearchOnEmptyString(false);`, or set it to true instead, do you still have the same problem? Also, I'm curious if it's the network call that is taking 5 second, or is it because we send the network call initially with a 5 second delay (for some weird reason). If you have a tool like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/), you can quickly check if the problem is on the network side (and Algolia's backend).

Comment: Thank you Guy for your answer. The problem appears to be about the wifi connection. After checking in with a network tool i saw that the first request goes with a 5 seconds delay. Then i switched to another wifi and problem disappered. Probably it is bacause of the the vpn.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the solution! I Hope you're enjoying InstantSearch for Android :)

Comment: We are more then satisfied with the speed of Algolia. But we had hard time on using algolia clients. You have to update your examples and documentations. Since the documentations are old we dig down on the code to find out how to integrate with algolia. Anyway, it is good and working now. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive feedback! Indeed, we are currently working on updating our examples and documentations to make it easier for devs to integrate. It is a priority now. Stay tuned :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad that the issue disappeared when you switched to another wifi.

For future readers that may encounter network issues with InstantSearch Android:

- First of all, build and run [one of our demo applications](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android-examples/)
- If you see no problem running the example application, you can try using a proxy like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to investigate what's happening between your app and the network

If your problem persists when running the examples, or if you are following the [documentation](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch-android/getting-started.html), send an email to `support@algolia.com` describing the issue with a sample of your code!